# Video Editor Add Image, Text contents in Video file swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-processing, video-editing

In my application user should be able to select a video from video library and also record video to camera . And user able to add some text and some stickers  marks using free hand (Drag and drop inspire by),Add Image, Text contents in Video file we need to merge added text and stickers marks in this video. And save to camera roll.